# Search different column names in different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, as an example:

```
content
- id
- title

news
- id
- myTitle
```

So I then want to be able to search both content.title and news.myTitle for the same keyword, however I can't use a join as there isn't a foreign key between the two tables. I've tried a few different queries but none returned the results I was expected so any help would be greatly appreciated. I only want a simple LIKE query to search title/myTitle in both tables.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with for _the same keyword_ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select content.title, 'content' as src_table from content where title = 'keyword'
union
select news.myTitle, 'news' as src_table from news where myTitle = 'keyword'
```

Comment: You have added aliases without updating select criteria.  The aliases are really not needed in this instance anyhow as they are simple selects

Comment: I removed them to simplify the query.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Is there a way to tell which query the row came from when I loop through the results? I only ask as I have a different parameter to set in the URL I return for each one and it'd rather not re-query each time to find out which table it came from.

Comment: I feel a bit bugged that this is precisely what the answer I gave had in from the start.

Answer (score 4):

UNION is your friend in this matter (background reading : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html)

```
(
    SELECT
        'content',
        id,
        title
    FROM content
    WHERE title LIKE '%.....%'
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        'news',
        id,
        myTitle AS title
    FROM news
    WHERE myTitle LIKE '%.....%'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about?

```
select id, title from content
where title like '%blah%'
union all
select id, myTitle from news
where title like '%blah%'
```

Notice if you don't use `union all` then you might lose a record there. It is not clear whether you need it or not.