# search two different MySQL tables with different fields

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I found help at this topic: [Search different column names in different tables in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375571/search-different-column-names-in-different-tables-in-mysql) but they are only referencing two fields per table in that topic and I wasn't able to generate an answer from my searches.

**EDIT :** I have also found this thread: [Combine two tables that have no common fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields) which gives a little more helpful information, but I am still not able to figure out how to combine these properly

I have never had the need to create a `JOIN` or `UNION` query, so this is all pretty new to me. So forgive me if there is an easy solution to this.

I need to run a query that will search through two different database tables that have completely different fields.

Here are the two queries I am trying to combine into one:

```
"SELECT * FROM seekers 
    WHERE (first_name LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (last_name LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (username LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (school LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (major LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (employer LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (position LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (background LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (interests LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (skills LIKE '%".$q."%')
    ORDER BY id DESC"

"SELECT * FROM companies 
    WHERE (company_name LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (username LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (industry LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (slogan LIKE '%".$q."%')
        OR (location LIKE '%".$q."%') 
    ORDER BY id"
```

After the query, I want to get all the fields into an array and display the data accordingly.

I guess the major problem I am having with this is deciding how I should go about combining the tables? Do I want to use a `JOIN` (inner or outer) or do I want to use a `UNION`?

I have tried to create a `VIEW` by doing this: `$this->mysqli->query("CREATE VIEW userTable AS (SELECT * FROM seekers) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM companies)");` but that didn't work, I'm guessing because the tables have far different fields.

**EDIT :** After trying some of the answers below, I have come up with this query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, username, school, major, employer, position, background, interests, skills 
    FROM seekers 
        WHERE (first_name LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (last_name LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (username LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (school LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (major LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (employer LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (position LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (background LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (interests LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (skills LIKE '%".$q."%')
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT company_name, username, industry, slogan, location, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL 
            WHERE (company_name LIKE '%".$q."%') 
                OR (username LIKE '%".$q."%') 
                OR (industry LIKE '%".$q."%') 
                OR (slogan LIKE '%".$q."%') 
                OR (location LIKE '%".$q."%')
```

I removed the `ORDER BY` clause because I was getting an error saying "Incorrect use of UNION and ORDER BY", so after removing the `ORDER BY` I get this error: "Query Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (company_name LIKE '%0%') OR (username LIKE '%0%') OR (industry LIKE '%0%')' at line 1"

Why is `$q` becoming 0 in the query after the union?

**EDIT #2 :** Here is a `JOIN` query I put together that actually returns data, but it doesn't return the correct data. I don't know if this will help answer the question, but I thought I would put it here anyway.

```
"SELECT * FROM seekers t1 LEFT JOIN companies t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE (t1.first_name LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t1.last_name LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t1.username LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t1.school LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t1.major LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t1.employer LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t1.position LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t1.background LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t1.interests LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t1.skills LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t2.company_name LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t2.username LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t2.industry LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t2.slogan LIKE '%".$q."%') OR (t2.location LIKE '%".$q."%')"
```

sorry for the formatting on the last query, SO messed it up when pasting.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407864/mysql-select-union-for-different-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a UNION you need to make sure the number of fields in each SELECT is equal. So in your example above you shouldn't use 'Select *' - do something like this:

Select t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3, t1.field4, t1.field5, t1.field6
From  .....
Where .....

Union

Select t2.field1, t2.field2, t2.field3, t2.field4, '', ''
From  .....
Where .....

If the number of fields in each Select are different add some blank ones to even it up.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Is this the easiest way to do something like this?

Comment: I'm open to correction but it's probably the most straight forward way!

Comment: I updated my question with a query I generated from yours and Jack's answers but I am still not able to get this working. Can you please view it to see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Just in case you're missing it make sure you have the ';' at the end of the query

Comment: yeah, i definitely have that there. And besides, not having the `;` at the end of a query would cause a php syntax error and not allow the script to run at all. That is definitely not the issue here.

Comment: just spotted it - in the second select you're missing 'FROM company'

Comment: Okay, so putting the `FROM companies` in there does give me results. I can't believe I missed that. But, the results are incorrect. It returns the same two users for every search query... any suggestions on how to avoid that?

Comment: Not sure on that one without seeing the dataset - but your results will be based on the criteria in the WHERE clause; could it be those 2 users are all you will get based on your criteria?

Answer (score 2):

You could try a UNION, but give each column name an alias. Make sure they are the in same order. See below as an example:

```
SELECT first_name col1, last_name col2 etc etc FROM seekers 
    WHERE (first_name LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (last_name LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (username LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (school LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (major LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (employer LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (position LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (background LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (interests LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (skills LIKE '%".$q."%')
    ORDER BY id DESC
UNION
SELECT company_name col1, username col2, etc etc FROM companies 
    WHERE (company_name LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (username LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (industry LIKE '%".$q."%') 
        OR (slogan LIKE '%".$q."%')
        OR (location LIKE '%".$q."%') 
    ORDER BY id
```

This will match the columns together in the same result set. ie, first_name and company_name will be shown in col1, and so on.

NOTE

1. With a UNION you need to select the same number of columns in both queries.
2. You need to match the data types
3. If you need to fake a column use null

Comment: I updated my question with some code following this answer. Please view it and see if you can tell where I am going wrong.

Comment: Add an alias for each column and see if you get the same error. The alias needs to be the same in both queries. `first_name col1` and `company_name col1`, `last_name col2` and `username col2` etc etc

Comment: I tried to add aliases and it didn't work. I've created a `JOIN` query that returns data, but it's not the correct data. I updated my question with that query.

Comment: It also need to be of the same type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126692/combine-multiple-query-results-in-mysql-by-column